# A plural verb with a singular subject: Is this like the royal "we"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-usage

Quoting from a novel:

> Sie haben Glück, mein Sohn. Seine Magnifizenz der Hochsekretär geruhen, Ihnen ein Paar Minuten seiner kostbaren Zeit zu widmen.

This seems to be a singular subject with a plural verb form. Is this akin to the custom by which kings and popes refer to themselves as "we"? Or did I miss something?

Comment: FYI: There is an Austrian satirical TV show, [*Wir sind Kaiser*](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wir+sind+kaiser), which makes frequent use of both the pluralis majestatis and another peculiarity, adressing somebody in third person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this akin to the custom by which kings and popes refer to themselves as "we"?

Yes it is.

> > ***Seine** Magnifizenz der Hochsekretär ... geruhen ...*

Is an indicator for this (now obsolete) form. Basically it is *pluralis majestatis*, that was used for high rank aristocrats, or even officials (like in your example).

Other examples of indicators:

> **Seine** Hochwohlgeboren Graf von Koks ... geruhen ...
>
> **Ihre** Majestät ... geruhen ...

Comment: .... and what about the phrase "mein Sohn"? In English an older man speaking informally may address a younger man as "son", but somehow I have the impression that this is more like the phrase "my son" by which a clergyman may address a member of his congregation, and that is a more formal usage. Is that what this is?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is this informal, as when, in English, an old man addresses a young man as "son", or is it somewhat formal, as when a clergyman addresses a parishioner as "my son"?

Comment: The actual question is not answered yet: From the grammar view "Seine Magnifizenz" is singular. It is an aristocratic term, but I see no plural and no pluralis majestatis.

Comment: @Nick The verb _geruhen_ is in plural form.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You're right. But anyhow there's a contradiction to the noun marker "seine" (is it a noun marker?)...

Comment: @Nick As explained, it's the same as using _pluralis majestatis_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "Seine Majestät" ist singular, "Ihre Majestät" would be plural (btw. the today usual "Sie" form is this from a grammar view).

Comment: @Nick : Why would "Ihre Majestät" be plural? If I say "Ihr Haus ist neu.", is "Ihr Haus" plural? And if so, would I be wrong to say "Ihr Haus ist neu." rather than "Ihr Haus sind neu."?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: It means "Ihre Majestät" as 3rd person plural. "Ihr Haus" is ambigious, can be 3rd person singular (female) or plural. Or in modern German the 3rd person plural as polite form, which remains plural from the grammar view.

Comment: @Nick : Would you say "Ihr Haus sind neu."? I would say "Ihr Haus ist neu.", since "ihr Haus" is plainly singular.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: The plural does not refer to the predicate (Haus) but to the subject (Ihr) of the sentence. Correct would be "Ihr seid der König". (So I would say "Ihr Haus ist neu." or "Ihre Häuser sind neu.")

Comment: @MichaelHardy A clergyman would usually address a person of his parish or somebody with lower social status as "Mein Sohn". "Seine Hochmagnifizienz" seems not be a word though. "Maginifizienz" is the head of a university nowadays. I old times he might have been a clergyman as well.

Comment: I feel like @MichaelHardy also asks about the meaning of "Sie" and "Ihnen" ... to clear that up: these are not pluralis majestatis, but the standard form of formally addressing the person who is being talked to (see also: formal vs informal "you" in german; "Sie"/"Ihnen" is the formal version of "du"/"dir").

Comment: Only now, a couple of years after posting this question, I'm noticing that you're saying the reason why the word "Seine" is used is _not_ that "Magnifizenz" is a feminine noun (although it is). Rather, in a phrase like "Seine Hochwohlgeboren Graf", that form is used because the noun is treated as if it were grammatically plural, although it refers to just one person.